# admin controller authentication using cancan gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am using cancan gem with rails3. Here I have same log in form for all roles. I have a admin section. Normal authentication check user log in or not but not check his role admin or not.

So normal user can see admin pages using admin url (myapp/com/admin/users), how to authenticate ?

Thanks
Prasad

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know `CanCan` is not for **authentication** but for **authorization**

Use something like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem for authentication. And `CanCan`'s `ability` class to enforce authorization.

You can also manually check if a user is permitted to perform an action using a `before_filter` hook.